# Why does releasing my array crash my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

If I release my first array after I copied it to the second array my app crashes. If I autorelease the first array everything works fine. Why? Is there a better way to copy the first array to the second array?

If I call this method I get a ECX_BAD_ACCESS, I am passing an empty array

```
-(NSArray *)loadSystemDetails
{
    AssortedCodeSnippets *acs = [[AssortedCodeSnippets alloc] init];
    NSArray *details;
    NSString *fp = [self tempPathAndFileName:[self systemDetailsFileName]];
    if ([acs fileExistsAtPath:fp]) {
        NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fp];
        details = array;
        [array release];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No File to Load");
        CreateSystem *cls = [[CreateSystem alloc] init];
        details = [cls loadData];
        [cls release];
        [self saveDataFile:details toPath:fp];
    }
    NSLog(@"details: %@",details);
    [acs release];
    return details;
}
```

If I autorelease array it work fine.

```
-(NSArray *)loadSystemDetails
{
    AssortedCodeSnippets *acs = [[AssortedCodeSnippets alloc] init];
    NSArray *details;
    NSString *fp = [self tempPathAndFileName:[self systemDetailsFileName]];
    if ([acs fileExistsAtPath:fp]) {
        NSArray *array = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fp]autorelease];
        details = array;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No File to Load");
        CreateSystem *cls = [[CreateSystem alloc] init];
        details = [cls loadData];
        [cls release];
        [self saveDataFile:details toPath:fp];
    }
```

Comment: Frankly, until you learn what a pointer is you should stick with plain old C, or even Java.  Objective-C is far to complex for a beginner.

Comment: Hey lighten up, everyone has to start somewhere, I could write my C knowledge on the back of a stamp but I seem to be doing ok with my development :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through this

**Key: M = release/retain message, C = sum of the release/retain messages**

```
                                                              // +----+---+
                                                              // | M  | C |
                                                              // +----+---+
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fp]; // | +1 | 1 |
details = array;                                              // |  0 | 1 |
[array release];                                              // | -1 | 0 |
                                                              // +----+---+
```

At this point you can see that you are going to be returning `details` which has a count of 0 therefore will have been deallocated already = crash.

Copy is the wrong term as you do not actually need a copy as such you just want your pointer `details` to point to a valid object therefore the following would be more correct

```
- (NSArray *)systemDetails
{
    NSString *filePath = [self tempPathAndFileName:[self systemDetailsFileName]];

    NSArray *details = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath] autorelease];

    if (!details) {

        NSLog(@"No File to Load");
        CreateSystem *cls = [[CreateSystem alloc] init];
        details = [cls loadData];
        [cls release]; cls = nil;
        [self saveDataFile:details toPath:filePath];

    }

    NSLog(@"details: %@",details);

    return details;
}
```

Here I am taking advantage of [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)'s method

> initWithContentsOfFile:
>
> ...[returns] nil if the file can’t be opened or the contents of the file can’t be parsed into an array

This cuts down some of the cruft and makes the method a bit easier to read. I also expanded the variable names to meaningful names (personal preference).

I have also renamed the method as the `load` art is superflous as essentially you are returning the system details the fact that they are being loaded is not not really a concern to the caller of the method.

It's also important to note that the other answers suggest that you take an additional retain/copy and then remember to release the returned result later on. This goes against cocoa convention as the method name does not contain new/init/copy therefore the callers f the method should not end up owning the result.

Comment: thanks for the reply and for the help. I'm still trying to figure out the whole Objective-C language.

Answer (score 1):

Send `details` assignment a `retain` message, when assigning `details` to point to `array` or the result of `cls`'s `-loadData` method. Be sure to `release` the `details` somewhere after the `-loadSystemDetails` method.

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, you're not actually copying `array` into `details`. Remember that both of these variables are *pointers* to arrays and not arrays themselves. Thus, the line `details = array` simply copies the location of the `array` into `details`. In other words, after this line, both variables are pointing to exactly the same array in memory. Therefore, when you call `release`, the object in memory is deallocated, and *both* `details` and `array` are now pointing to a non-existent object. If you want to actually copy the array in memory, use

```
details = [array copy]
```

Remember that eventually you'll have to call `release` on `details` when you want to get rid of this object.